# exciting or more of customizing for users while posting their questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

All SE sites must have a feature where the first 1 hour to answer my posted question, should be reserved for my favorites, who I think have better explanation methods or something exciting as this.

Comment: Closing as off-topic: this meta site is for things that relate to Pro Webmasters, not the entire network. This table feature request is not something that's specific to this site: it would affect other sites as well, and they should be able to comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would this possibly accomplish?
If I'm not one of your favorites but know the answer, the system actively preventing me from responding immediately is *not* going to result in my setting an alarm or something to come back and do it later. So then you're stuck hoping one of your favorite people *does* know the answer, which is not at all guaranteed. In fact, on top of the system-level annoyance, it *tells me* you don't think enough of me to make me a favorite, which will possibly just make the blocked user even more hostile toward you.

(Now go work on your accept rate.)